# point select with angular Ng2GoogleChartsModule (google chart)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-visualization

I've install **Ng2GoogleChartsModule** on my Ionic 2 app. I want select a point by button click. On original Google chart there are setSelection() function, but I don't find it in Ng2GoogleChartsModule.

Can you help me.

> THIS WORK

let googleChartWrapper = this.cchart1.wrapper;
this.cchart1.redraw();

> THIS DON'T WORK

let googleChartWrapper = this.cchart1.wrapper;
this.cchart1.setSelection();

ERROR : setSelection it's not a function

Answer (score 0):

`setSelection` is a chart method
you can use `getChart` on the wrapper, to get the chart,
then set the selection...

```
let googleChartWrapper = this.cchart1.wrapper;
googleChartWrapper.getChart().setSelection(...);
```